# How to get WordPress image thumbnail link? ( not featured image )

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

I am trying to build a simple gallery with WordPress Advanced Custom Fields and the repeater field plugin. I need to display a thumbnail image which you click to enlarge the main image (I am using Fancybox). Does anyone know whether it is possible to get the link to the image thumbnail WordPress automatically generates?

I can get the main image link:
/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/slide1.jpg

But need to get this image link: 
/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/slide1-150x150.jpg

Here is my code:

```
<?php if(get_field('gallery')): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('gallery')): ?>
            <a class="fancybox" href="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt="" width="200px;" height="auto"/></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('video_link')): ?>
            <a class="fancybox-media" href="<?php the_sub_field('video_link_snippet'); ?>"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('video_image'); ?>"/></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey there! Please let me know if you need any additional help with this problem. If this problem is resolved, please consider choosing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely do this with Advanced Custom Fields and Wordpress. To do so, go into the custom fields and change the sub field 'image' so that it returns the Image Object instead of the Image URL. [See 'return value' here.](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/acf-image-field-edit.jpg)

Once this field returns the object, try var_dumping the field to see your URL options:

```
var_dump(the_sub_field('image'));
```

This should show you the different thumbnail sizes enabled in your system and allow you to easily get the thumbnail you'd like. One possible example:

```
// Get image object with all sizes...
$image = the_sub_field('image');
$size = 'thumbnail';

// Get URL from sizes based on our $size var
$url = $image['sizes'][$size];

// Now we have the thumbnail URL
echo $url;
```

Let me know if you run into problems! For more documentation and many more options, try the **[Advanced Custom Fields documentation for the Image field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have tried var_dumping the field but it doesn't display any results for 'sizes' =>. I have created various image sizes in my functions.php file, should it be displaying these?

Comment: Hey there, I saw you posted the var_dump here momentarily and it did say 'sizes'. Could you re-post the var_dump results and I'll provide a sample of how to get the particular thumbnail from it?

Comment: `array
  0 => 
    array
      'image' => 
        array
          'id' => int 54
          'alt' => string '' (length=0)
          'title' => string 'slide1' (length=6)
          'caption' => string '' (length=0)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
          'mime_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          'url' => string 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/slide1.jpg' (length=54)
          'width' => int 1000
          'height' => int 630
          'sizes' => 
            array
              ...`

Comment: I was using this code to general the var_dump: `<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

echo '<pre>';
 var_dump( $image );
echo '</pre>';

?>`

Comment: Iv simplified the code to try to get just the URL of the image but for some reason its not working. I have looked at the documentation and can't see what is wrong with my code... `<?php if( have_rows('gallery_image') ): ?>
         <?php while( have_rows('gallery_image') ): the_row(); ?>
          <?php 
           $image = the_sub_field('image');
           $url = $image['url'];
           echo '<a>' . $url . '</a>';
          ?>

                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Hey there man! Sorry for the delay. Your first var_dump here shows that the 'size's array exsists, but it only shows the content as "...". To view the content of the sizes array, could you try this: <?php $image = get_field('image'); echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $image[0]['image']['sizes'] ); echo '</pre>'; ?> 

Please note that this may be incorrect. I had to manually format the code you provided to see how the array was nested, this is what I ended up with: http://devimg.next-www.com/20141210150023821.png

Comment: That's great it is displaying loads of various image sizes now! I was having a bit of trouble trying to make the code work in my previous comment, do you think you might be able to take a look to see what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you echoed the url into the <a></a> tags instead of within the href="" element within the <a></a> tags. Should be like this:
<?php if( have_rows('gallery_image') ): ?> 
 <?php while( have_rows('gallery_image') ): the_row(); ?> 
  <?php $image = the_sub_field('image'); $url = $image['url']; echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Click Here!</a>'; ?> 
 <?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Thanks once again for your help but I have used your code and it still doesn't generate any results for the URL. It just shows all the details for the image then shows the 'Click Here' button with an empty href. The code generated looks like this: `54, , slide1, , , image/jpeg, http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/slide1.jpg, 1000, 630, Array
<a href="">Click Here!</a>`I have no idea why its not working as it should?

Comment: Ah sorry, I just noticed an obvious mistake and fixed it. Turns out there were more than one. using the_sub_field will echo the field instead of return it. This means that if you want to set a variable equal to the field you must use get_sub_field, not the_sub_field. Try this now:

<?php if( have_rows('gallery_image') ): ?> <?php while( have_rows('gallery_image') ): the_row(); ?> <?php $image = get_sub_field('image'); $url = $image['url']; echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Click Here!</a>'; ?> <?php endwhile; ?> <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Also, if you're finding this helpful providing me (and anyone else who helps you) with simple upvotes will encourage future assistance. This way, at least the people helping get a little something out of the deal- even if it's fake rep points.

Comment: That's great I have tried that code and it is working now. Thank you very much for all your help!!! :-)